# How do you avoid Belial's poison attack?

Tags: diablo-iii

My wife and I just recently finished Belial in Normal and obviously the fight's gonna get much worse in Nightmare. I am a Monk and she's a Demon Hunter. Aside from the fact that Belial can't damage me that much because of my high armor(I have twice her armor since I have a skill for that), is there a way to avoid this? I tried telling her to go into a corner but she still gets hit and immediately just dies(I do know here items are great and she has a high Vit).

Is there a secret spot that she can stay in while she shoots Belial? What happened was me trying torevive her(Belial doesn't damage me that much) before we hit the final blow.

Or better, can I just kill Belial and she stil gets the exp(and items) after I revive her?

Comment: She will indeed get exp and items even if dead. In fact, if she dies early, like when the snake men first attack, she can even get the achievement for not getting hit by any of Belial's attacks if you go on to finish the entire fight while she's dead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to just stop attacking and move the moment there's some green under your feet.

You can get back to the fight as soon as you're back in the clear, and you won't take any damage. What's more important, staying alive, or a bit more damage?

When he does his huge multiple poison attack, just don't stop moving until it's over. Keep moving and aim for the spots that either were just poisoned (so they're turning back to normal) or are currently normal. So long as she doesn't get hit, she can join in the fight again once it's over.

If she equips strafe, then she can keep attacking even while moving if she really feels like she needs to put out that extra DPS instead of staying alive.

Comment: This has been the best advice that's why I selected this. But all the others also deserve plus points. :) Still, moving while the multiple poison attack is in effect is the best chance of surviving.

Answer (score 3):

Belial's poison attack only lasts a few seconds but it can be deadly. It took about three or four tries with me (Demon Hunter) and my buddy (Barbarian) on Nightmare.

I ended up using a Sentry that constantly attacked Belial even while we were avoiding the poison attack which seemed to help.

Definitely during the poison "phase" you should be more defensive and just try to avoid the green as much as possible, then focus your attacks when it is over.

Answer (score 3):

Me and a friend are running the same combo and whenever I got close to dying or my friend felt that I was getting hit too often he popped [mantra of healing](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/mantra-of-healing) with the *Boon of Protection* as active skill rune. It shields you from some of the damage while also giving you extended regen so its *PERFECT* for Belial!

Also, if you want to heal your friend up be sure to stand close to him while using [breath of heaven](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/breath-of-heaven) (12 yard radius). I had tons of situations when i used [vault](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault) to escape with low hp and barely got out of range and therefore couldnt get the healing.

If you guys feel you can't keep your hp up in the higher difficulties I would also give you the tip to use [Serenity](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/serenity) with the *Peaceful Repose* rune. Your friend should use [Preparation](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/preparation) with the *Battle Scars* rune. Both are basically a second hp pot for free every 20 second for you and every 45 for your demonhunter friend.

Comment: wow i didn't have mantra of healing back then but i sure do now. also will the skill with that circle of protection work against attacks? or does it just repel monsters from getting too close to you?

Answer (score 1):

With DH, I stayed on the outer edge far from Belial using sentry combined with shadow power until it ran out. While charging, I just ran trying to avoid his poisonous circles. Also, remain vigilant for the red life globes which appear closer to him. Then get back.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after half an hour of failed attempts with a demon hunter, the answer was to focus my whole character on life and evasion.

Buy the best +life equipment you can find, use gems to give yourself life stealing on your weapon, craft equipment if you can't buy it, and focus skills on evasion or life.

Then do your best to keep your health up and avoid being hit, while attacking as the lowest priority. This worked well for me.